# I want know is there any way to schedule mysql and send email using mysql scheduler?

Tags: mysql

i am working on project where i need to send email to bid winner so i want to use mysql scheduler where it can retrieve the data form columns and send email to the bid winner email address.I use this But its not working.

```
CREATE EVENT `exec`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
  STARTS '2013-02-10 00:00:00'
  ENDS '2015-02-28 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
  call delete_rows_links();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `MySQL` to send emails to users. Ideally, the logic needs to be present inside the Application that interacts with `MySQL` `db` rather than the `db` itself. It can do the following:

- Execute let's say every minute, it can be a `cron`/scheduled job configured as per scheduler/cron expression (you can look up and generate `cron` expressions [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/).
- Query `MySQL` `db` and get the records
- Iterate through the record and call `email` service to send emails